# Backup Windows 10 with an Antivirous

Tags: windows-10, backup

This is a general question. I have heard from some people that it is not ok to make a backup of Windows with antivirus already installed in it. I have no idea is it right or not. I want to make a backup of my Windows 10 with a 3 party software like Acronis. I would really appreciate if someone can clarify is it ok or not to make a backup with an antivirus ( for example 360 Total Security ) already installed in the Laptop.

Comment: I think it is ok, if antivirus will not block backup from low-level access (normal antivirus should not; don't know is 360TS normal or not). Also, check documentation of your backup solution about antiviruses and your antivirus about backups. Actually there were some issues with antiviruses in Acronis Backup, but they can be solved by user: https://kb.acronis.com/content/46430 "Acronis software needs exclusive access to your machine's disk to operate. This means that antivirus software may conflict with Acronis products. Add Acronis ..files and folders to the exclusions.. allowed and trusted "

Comment: @osgx Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have no idea is it right or not.

If you have no idea, check the documentation of both program products. Some antiviruses may block other software from directly accessing your hard drive, as this action was popular in viruses to hide from OS and antiviruses. But popular backup solutions are known and probably marked as trusted in normal antiviruses.

For example, Acronis has instruction how to mark its backup solutions as trusted (or excluded) in several antiviruses: https://kb.acronis.com/content/46430